# tail estimate for ''real zeta function''

Tags: real-analysis

I have the next question, if we take $t \in \mathbb{R}$ (maybe $t > 1$) we can estimate the tail of the serie
$$\sum_{n} \frac{1}{n^t}?$$
for the $n \geq K$, $K$ fix positive integer.

Comment: See the proof [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence), or the "Integral Test" section [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/EstimatingSeries.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, we can estimate the tail of the series. Here is how :

It is proved that if $\sum{a_n}$ is convergent and $f(n)=a_n$ where $f$ is a continuous, positive, decreasing function for $x\geq K$, then the tail $T_K=\sum_{n={K+1}}^\infty a_n$ of the series satisfy
$$
\int_{K+1}^\infty f(x)dx\leq T_k \leq\int_K^\infty f(x)dx
$$

We can use this theorem for $\sum_{n}\frac{1}{n^t}$ with $t>1$ since the series is then convergent and $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^t}$ satisfy the requirements. You can prove its convergence for example with the *Integral Test* as proposed by David Mitra.

Hence we compute
$$
\int_{K+1}^\infty\frac{1}{x^t}dx=\frac{1}{(t-1)(K+1)^{t-1}},\quad \text{and}\quad\int_K^\infty\frac{1}{x^t}dx=\frac{1}{(t-1)K^{t-1}}
$$
to get
$$
\frac{1}{(t-1)(K+1)^{t-1}} \leq T_k \leq \frac{1}{(t-1)K^{t-1}}
$$
so that we can approximate the tail by taking the middle value :
$$
T_k\simeq \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{(t-1)(K+1)^{t-1}}+\frac{1}{(t-1)K^{t-1}} \right)=\frac{(K+1)^{1-t}+K^{1-t}}{2(t-1)}
$$